# Finding the most frequent value in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I want to find most frequent product each customer has purchased. my data set is like this :

```
CustomerID     ProdID    FavouriteProduct
    1              A              ?
    1              A              ?
    1              A              ?
    1              B              ?
    1              A              ?
    1              A              ?
    1              A              ?
    1              B              ?
    2              A              ?
    2              AN             ?
    2              G              ?
    2              C              ?
    2              C              ?
    2              F              ?
    2              D              ?
    2              C              ?
```

There are so many products,So i cannot put them in a pivot table.

Answer would look like this :

```
CustomerID     ProdID    FavouriteProduct
    1              A              A
    1              A              A
    1              A              A
    1              B              A
    1              A              A
    1              A              A
    1              A              A
    1              B              A
    2              A              C
    2              AN             C
    2              G              C
    2              C              C
    2              C              C
    2              F              C
    2              D              C
    2              C              C
```

The query may look like this:

```
Update table
set FavouriteProduct = (Select 
                            CustomerID, Product, Max(Count(Product)) 
                        From Table 
                        group  by CustomerID, Product) FP
```

Comment: Pivot has nothing to do with this. First work out the query that returns each customers favourite product. You're almost there. Then we can help with an update.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid   -I know, I just said if the number of products was three or four, we could easily find favorite product through a pivot table. but now?

Comment: Go to the bottom of this page http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/find-frequent-values/ and see if you can adapt the SQL to return a list of all customers with their favourite product.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Do you need any further help?

Comment: I posted an answer. I think it's correct. would you please check it? @Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nick, i found a way to find the most frequent value. i share with you how it works :

```
   Select CustomerID,ProductID,Count(*) as Number 
   from table A 
   group by CustomerID,ProductID 
   having Count(*)>= (Select Max(Number) from (Select CustomerID,ProductID,Count(*) as Number from table B where B.CustomerID= A.CustomerID  group by CustomerID,Product)C)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the most frequent product is to use `row_number()`:

```
select customerid, productid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then productid end) over (partition by customerid) as favoriteproductid
from (select customerid, productid, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from customer c
      group by customerid, productid
     ) cp;
```

Answer (score 2):

To return the rows exactly as you have described in the question, you could try using a table expression (I used a CTE in my example) to first return a popularity ranking, where the higher the number, the more popular the product for each customer.

```
WITH RankTable AS (
  SELECT
    CustomerID, ProductID, COUNT(*) AS Popularity
  FROM TableA
  GROUP BY CustomerID, ProductID
)
```

Then the full results table can be returned by first performing an inner join on the original table (TableA) and the table expression (RankTable), and then using a window function to create the values in the FavoriteProduct column.

```
SELECT 
    P.CustomerID
  , P.ProductID
  , FIRST_VALUE(P.ProductID) OVER(
      PARTITION BY R.CustomerID
      ORDER BY R.Popularity DESC, R.ProductID) AS FavoriteProduct
FROM TableA AS P
  INNER JOIN RankTable AS R
    ON P.CustomerID = R.CustomerID
    AND P.ProductID= R.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your SQL doesn't perform fast enough and you have customers also in a smaller table, this might work better::

```
select C.CustomerId, R.ProductID
from Customer C
outer apply (
  Select top 1 ProductID,Count(*) as Number 
  from table A 
  where A.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
  group by ProductId
  order by Number desc 
) R
```

Answer (score 1):

This one, based on the example at the end of this page: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/find-frequent-values/ might be quicker:

```
SELECT CustomerID, ProdID, Cnt 
FROM 
(
    SELECT CustomerID, ProdID, COUNT(*) as Cnt, 
    RANK() OVER (
       PARTITION BY CustomerID
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS Rnk 
    FROM YourTransactionTable
    GROUP BY CustomerID, ProdID
) x 
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

This one uses a `RANK()` function. In this case you don't have to join back to the same table (meaning there's a lot less work required)

Now to update your existing data, I like to wrap my dataset in a WITH to make debugging a little easier and the final update a bit simpler:

```
;WITH
(
  SELECT CustomerID, ProdID, Cnt 
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT CustomerID, ProdID, COUNT(*) as Cnt, 
     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS Rnk 
     FROM TransactionTable
     GROUP BY CustomerID, ProdID
  ) x 
  WHERE Rnk = 1
) As SRC

 UPDATE FavouriteTable
 SET Favourite = SRC.ProdID
 FROM SRC
 WHERE SRC.CustomerID = Favourite.CustomerID
```